# Python TypeError: loadshotlist_comp() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I got a quick question which I cannot figure out. The problem has been described before, I looked into the search results, but I don't know what I am doing wrong in my case.

Here is the little extract, I hope it's enough as I cut some auto generated code to make it compact for you.

The Error is:

> File ".............py", line 345, in retranslateUi
>       self.loadshotlist_comp(_translate)
>
> TypeError: loadshotlist_comp() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    self.loadshotlist_comp(self, _translate)

def loadshotlist_comp (self, _translate):
    with open(pathToShotlist) as fp:
        linelist = fp.readlines()
        itemcnt = 0

        for line in linelist:
            print(line.strip())
            item = self.list_comp.item(0)
            item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", line.strip()))
            itemcnt += 1

    fp.close()
```

Removing self from the method parameters results in

> in retranslateUi self.loadshotlist_comp(_translate)
>
> TypeError: loadshotlist_comp() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given and self.list_comp.item(0) is marked as an "unresolved reference" in pycharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass `self` when calling a method; that is already done for you because you called the method via `self...` in the first place.

```
self.loadshotlist_comp(_translate)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already tried that but then:
in retranslateUi
    self.loadshotlist_comp(_translate)
TypeError: loadshotlist_comp() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

and self.list_comp.item(0) is marked as an "unresolved reference" in pycharm

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Call the method like Daniel suggested but leave self self in parameter list of the called method. Thanks.